# Prediction interval for regression with time series data

Tags: regression, time-series, autoregressive, prediction-interval

Suppose that ${y_{t}}$ and ${x_{t}}$ are time series variables. A simple linear regression model with autoregressive errors of order ${p}$, say AR(P), can be written as

\begin{equation}
    y_{t}= \beta_{0}+\beta_{1} x_{t} +w_{t}, \hspace{0.5 cm} t=1, 2, ..., n (1)
\end{equation}
where

${y_{t}}$ is the value of the response variable at period ${t}$.

${\beta_{0}}$ and ${\beta_{1}}$ are parameters.

Time, ${t}$, is a known constant which is an explanatory variable.

let's suppose ${w_{t}}$ to be an auto-regressive process.The process is giving as follows:
\begin{equation}
    w_{t}=\sum _{i=1}^{p}\phi_{t}w_{t-i} + z_{t}  (2)
\end{equation}
where ${ z_{t}}$ is called disturbance or error terms.

By applying the back-shift operator to (2), the AR($p$) process is given by the equation
\begin{equation*}
\varphi(B) w_{t}= z_{t}, \hspace{ 0.5 cm } t= 1, 2, ..., n.
\end{equation*}

$\varphi(B)$ is known as the characteristic polynomial of the process and its roots determine when the process is stationary or not. If we assume that an inverse operator, $\varphi^{-1}(B)$, exists, then ${w_{t}=\varphi^{-1}(B)z_{t}}$. So the model (1) can be written as

\begin{equation}
y_{t}= \beta_{0}+\beta_{1} x_{t} +\varphi^{-1}(B)z_{t}, \hspace{0.5 cm} t=1, 2, ..., n. (3)
\end{equation}

If we multiply all elements of the equation (3) by $\varphi(B)$ , we get
\begin{equation}
y^{*}_{t}= \beta^{*}_{0}+\beta_{1} t^{*} +z_{t}, \hspace{0.5 cm} t=1, 2, ..., n.       (4)
\end{equation}

where

$ y^{*}_{t}     = \varphi(B)y_{t}     = y_{t}-\phi_{1}y_{t-1} - ...- \phi_{p}y_{t-p}$

$ x^{*}_{t}      = \varphi(B)x_{t}     = x_{t}-\phi_{1}x_{t-1} - ...- \phi_{p}x_{t-p}$

$ \beta^{*}_{0}   = \varphi(B)\beta_{0} = \left( 1-\phi_{1}- \phi_{2}-...-\phi_{p}\right)\beta_{0} $

Thus, model (4) is just the usual linear regression with the unobserved $\{z_{t}\}$. We assume that the unobserved $\{z_{t}\}$ is a sequence of i.i.d random variables ${E(z_{t})=0}$, ${E(z^{2}_{t})=\sigma^{2}}$, with probability density function (p.d.f)  $f(z)$ and cumulative distribution function (c.d.f) ${F(z)= \int_{-\infty}^{z}f(u)du}$. The ${h}$- step- ahead linear predictor of ${\hat{y}_{n+h|1, 2, ..., n}}$, for ${y_{n+h}}$, ${h \geq 1}$ based on $\{y_{t}\}_{t=1}^{n}$ is defined recursively by

\begin{equation}
\hat{y}^{*}_{n+h}= \hat{\beta}^{*}_{0}+\hat{\beta}_{1}x^{*}_{ n+h} 
\end{equation}

and $\hat{z}_{n+h}=y^{*}_{n+h}-\hat{y}^{*}_{n+h}$ as the $h$- step-ahead prediction residuals.

Given ${x^{*}_{n+h}}$, an approximate ${1-\alpha}$ prediction interval for $\hat{y}^{*}_{n+h}$ is given by

\begin{equation}
\hat{y}^{*}_{n+h} \pm  q_{Empirical} 
\end{equation}

where  $q_{Empirical}$ is quantile function of the empirical of $(\hat{z}_{n+h})$.

It is clearly the interpretation of the prediction interval for $\hat{y}^{*}_{n+h}$ is not easy.

My question:  How to get a prediction interval for original variable $\hat{y}_{n+h}$?

Note: $(\hat{z}_{n+h})$ is not normal.

Comment: Hi: What software are you using to do the estimation ? If R, that would mean arima with  xreg= TRUE and an intercept.  If so, can't you just get the CI for the AR(p) process so a CI for $w_{n+h}$ and then use that to get the CI for $y_{n+h}$.